# Webservice sometimes not deployed in the EAR

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I have a SOAP service that is not getting deployed every time I deploy my project.

Something like this:

```
 @WebService(serviceName = "MyWebService",targetNamespace="http://MyWebService.company.com/")

@Stateless()
public class MyWebService {

@WebMethod(operationName = "getMyMethod")
public List<OEntityAction> getMyMethod(@WebParam(name = "myParam") String myParam) {
    return "test";
}
```

Sometimes it does not get deployed and sometimes it does.

I'm using GlassFish 4.1

Comment: What kind of error do you get when it does not?

Comment: no errors just when i click at the deployed Ear from the glassfish console i don't see view end point link beside webservice and the webservice doesn't work

Comment: What happens of you access test and wsdl links provided by glassfish console?

Comment: actually i knew what is the problem i used org.apache.cmis  version 0.10.0 which contains jax-ws-rt.jar which has some problems with soap services